# Give permission 777 for UNIX files using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I want to give 777 permission for the files in UNIX and change that file as DOS file.

I want to achieve this in shellscript file. I will pass the partial file name from command prompt. Example: if the file name is employeesalary, employeejob then if i pass employee in the command prompt then all the file which starts with employee will be given access to 777 and also it needs to be changed as DOS file.

```
filename={$1}
chmod 777 $filename*
u2d -i $filename*
```

When i run the above code i am getting the below error.

```
chmod: WARNING: can't access employee* 

can't open employee*: No such file or directory in some location it specified
```

But when i run these commands alone in command prompt its working fine

```
chmod 777 employee*
u2d -i employee*
```

Comment: ShellCheck warns that your `{` and `}` are literal, and it's because you need a `$`: `filename=${1}`.

Comment: Why do you want `777` permissions? Do these files need to be executable and modifiable by everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a separate variable here. Just do

```
chmod 777 "$1"* && u2d -i "$1"*
```

If you prefer it as three lines:

```
filename="$1"
chmod 777 "$filename"* || exit $?
u2d -i "$filename"*
```

That said, 777 (world-writable, world-executable) is probably not a good idea. Would 755 (`rwxr-xr-x`) or even 644 (`rw-r--r--`) work for you? If so, that would be better.